# Calculate Remaining Spent on a budget list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, calculated-column

Goal: Trying to calculate remaining spent on a budget list where item expenses are grouped per object code. Every object code has a fixed amount of money against which the item expenses are deducted.

Example:

```
Object code ABC = 100,000
Item 1 = $50000
Item 2 = $30000
Remaining Spent = 100,000 - 50,000 = 50,000 
                  50,000 - 30,000 = 20,000
```

I have 2 lists. One with object codes and their assigned budgets. Another list with item details.

Challenge: How do I deduct expenses from the total amount per object code for every item's actuals?

Level: I am looking for a out of the box solution. Thank You!

Comment: I guess OOTB it is not possible. you have to go for other options

Comment: What other options are you thinking of? Are there any workflow options?

Comment: Can u provide more info? what do you want to do with this remaining amount, display somewhere, or just store in list? Is the amount used in an item is gonna change?

Comment: Can you provide how are you planning to create the 2 list. It might help in providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**List 1 : Planned**

```
Object Code | Budget | Pending Budget
A           | 10000  | 10000
B           | 20000  | 20000
B           | 30000  | 30000
D           | 40000  | 40000
E           | 50000  | 50000
F           | 60000  | 60000
```

**List 2 : Actual**

```
Planned Object Code | Actual 
A                   | 1000
B                   | 2000
C                   | 500
D                   | 100
A                   | 1500
A                   | 500
B                   | 1000
C                   | 100
```

1. List : Planned - Set Pending Budget = Budget initially
2. Set SharePoint designer workflow 2013 on List 2 - Actual.
3. For each new item in Actual - Get value of 'Planned Object Code' in a variable.
4. Based on 'Planned Object Code 'variable, get value of 'Pending Budget' from List 1 corresponding to Object code.
5. Subtract the List 2 - Actual value from 'Pending budget' variable.
6. Update List 1 - Pending budget column value